# Ubuntu 13.10 doesn't boot up after successful installation

Tags: installation, nvidia, 13.10, gpu-driver

Installed Ubuntu first time on my pc. Flashed it on my flash-drive,  ran it on my computer and decided to install, after successful installation computer restarts and I only see white line on black blank screen. Again boot from flash drive, run installation and face the same problem.

Computer specifications:
CPU: Intel Core i5-2310 2.90GHz
Motherboard: MSI MS-7732
RAM: DDR3, 4096 МБ (2х 2048 МБ)
HDD: SAMSUNG HD161HJ (149 ГБ)
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTS 450

Comment: Computer is connected to the internet.

Comment: Likely duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/401073/nvidia-not-working-after-most-recent-update

Comment: David thank you for  your comment, but how it's duplicate? That guy had problem with nvidia driver, not same for me. I have problem with booting up ubuntu 13.10 but I installed OEM version and after it I booted ubuntu. I just want to know why ubuntu doesn't boot after normal installation.

Comment: There was a recent (last 7 days) update (to Ubuntu) that caused issues for Nvidia graphics. I eventually gave up and re-installed, resolve issue. *I don't know if that was your issue, but it **might** be.*

Comment: I don't know this, I just downloaded latest stable version (13.10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your boot loader's installation failed. Boot on your Live drive, and try to reinstall it. In order to do so, select *Try Ubuntu* when prompted, wait for the environment to load, and open a terminal by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Become root by typing `sudo -i` an proceed with the following commands :

```
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda # Install GRUB on sda (adapt this line, see below)
update-grub # Generate configuration.
```

**Note** : you can find your hard drive's device file (`/dev/sdX`) by doing :

```
fdisk -l # As root, again.
```

You'll recognise your partitions, and hard drives. On most computers, there is only one hard drive, and the kernel loads it on `/dev/sda`.

Reboot, and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Can you give me detailed information where to write this code and how to install it as root. I'n noob in linux :(

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I'll try this...

Comment: Writing from linux, after command: "grub-install --recheck /dev/sda" terminal writes this: "Path `/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting." What does it means?

Comment: Please give this a try : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair (2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu). You'll have better instructions.

Comment: Ok. Will try this one.

Comment: I've done that instruction. Now what to do?

Comment: Read the page, follow the instructions to make a Recommended repair. The page explains quite correctly, you only need to follow.

Comment: okay. I hope, after this procedure it'll install Linux completely.

Comment: Successfully booted up after OEM installation, I don't know why normal installation doesn't work. Happy that ubuntu booted. But the issue with normal installation isn't solved.

Comment: Boot-Repair provides a paste.ubuntu.com/XXX link when it finishes its work. This might contain relevent information about your previous error.

Comment: Here it is: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6704841/

Comment: But I don't understand anything...