# Clean Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit install crashes on NVidia 8400M G 128 MB

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, 64-bit, freeze

After installing a clean Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit on my Asus F3SC it keeps crashing probably due to the graphics driver. After a few seconds/minutes the screen becomes dirty/garbled with some flashing here and there, and pretty soon the whole system just freezes. This happens using the default graphics driver but I also tried to install various other NVidia drivers such as the one from the X-SWAT ppa and older drivers too. I tried the nouveau driver too but it didn't work either.

To make sure that my hardware works I installed Windows XP and tested it for days using 2D/3D, and there were no problems.

So what can I do now?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe this is related to NVidia Optimus?

Comment: Likely duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/401073/nvidia-not-working-after-most-recent-update

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. Clean Ubuntu **13.10** 32-bit install. After a few seconds the screen becomes garbled with flashing parts, and the laptop freezes. I have an **Acer Aspire 5520G** with **Nvidia GeForce 8400M G**.

For now, I've found installing bumblebee helped, but my screen only runs in a much lower resolution than it should (**1024x768**). I don't know how to solve that yet. At least, it works and I can use my laptop.

The command I used in the terminal was:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

Obviously, you need to be connected to the Internet to run it. I'm hoping to find out how to set the resolution to **1280x800**.